# Обязательные input в таблицу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

День добрый.

Имеется таблица вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

первые три столбца заполняются циклом из базы данных, столбцы с чекбоксом и инпутом в цикле заполняются отдельно.

По нажатию на кнопку, строки с отмеченным чекбоксом должны записываться в другую базу вне зависимости от того, есть ли текст в инпуте.

Как можно запретить отправку строки, если чекбокс отмечен, а  инпут пустой? 
И возможно ли это?

Обязательный атрибут для инпута делает обязательными все инпуты в таблице, следовательно строки, не отмеченные чекбоксом, тоже выделяются как обязательные.

```
<table border="1px solid black">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td><input name="textstring" type="text"></td>
      <td><input name="check" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>45</td>
     <td><input name="textstring" type="text"></td>
      <td><input name="check" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td><input name="textstring" type="text"></td>
      <td><input name="check" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<input type="button" name="act" value="Актуально">

<input type="button" name="nonact" value="Не актуально">
```

Comment: Может быть стоит просто проверять форму перед отправкой? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+javascript

Answer (score 1):

Так как у вас стоит тег `Jquery` — пример запрета установки `checkbox`:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
  let di = $(this).attr('data-input');
  let val = $(`.td-input_${di}`).val();
  if (val.length === 0 ){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    // Активирует кнопку если заполнен комментарий
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="td-input_1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="td-input-cb" data-input="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="td-input_2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="td-input-cb" data-input="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Изменить">
```

По аналогии можно проверять и перед отправкой на сервер.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, согласен) Изначально хотел по другому и забыл удалить.

Comment: спасибо, вы пишете, что можно проверять и перед отправкой, то есть данную функцию можно привязать к кнопке?

Comment: @YaZh конечно, если бы вы ещё и код к вопросу прикладывали.

Comment: выше в вопросе код самой таблицы. код отправки на сервер громоздкий, но суть его в том, что пользователь отмечает чекбоксами нужные строки и нажимает на одну из кнопок "актуально" или "не актуально". в зависимости от name кнопки в базу данных записывается значение "актуально" или не "актуально".
мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку не актуально, скрипт проверял, есть ли у отмеченной чекбоксом строки текст в текстовом поле, и если его нет, то запрещал бы запись в базу данных, пока пользователь не напишет что-то в текстовое поле

Comment: А зачем отправлять вообще запрос, если не пройдена валидация?

Comment: Суть в том, что отмечать как актуальное можно и без заполненного инпута, а вот для отметки не актуальное комментарий обязателен.
И я хочу знать, возможно ли сделать проверку заполненности инпута только при нажатии на кнопку "отметить как не актуальное".

Comment: @YaZh, так вы хотели (добавил блок кнопки)?